# How can I lock whitespace characters from the text field in real time?

Tags: android, android-layout, sdk, android-widget

I have a login activity and I want to lock whitespace characters from the username textfield in real time. I mean not from the class. directly from the xml activity if is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "in real time", "not from the class" and "directly from the xml activity"?

Comment: I mean while you are writing in the text field and try to write a whitespace characters then just dont allow you. it's ok now? @Zabri

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't understand where you wanted to implement such behaviour. Never mind.

Comment: I thought it was possible to configure it from the xml of the activity but I see that I can't. so I will configure it by listener in mu class. @Zabri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, your priority during UI/UX design is to prevent your user from getting into trouble in the first place, rather than catching problems they might create.  I apologize for resurrecting the ghost of 1980s business buzzwords, but you want to be proactive and keep them from happening at all, as opposed to reactive and trying to put out fires once they've already started.

Your issue becomes much more manageable if you implement a custom key listener that consumes characters that you don't allow.  Accompany your edit text with some sort of notification that whitespace is not allowed so that the user doesn't start thinking that your code is broken because they can't enter what they think they should be able to enter.

Take a look [here](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/15/filtering-data-in-edittext-component-in-android/)

Comment: Thanks for the help @MarsAtomic I thought it was possible from xml file too but that link will help too.

Comment: You can use android:inputType in xml, but that limits you to numerals vs other characters IIRC, which won't give you the level of control you want.